# How would a vast large Solar Storm similar to the Carrington event now effect our modern society?

Tags: electromagnetism, astrophysics, plasma-physics, sun

Basically I've read upon this [article](https://in-mashable-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/in.mashable.com/science/24574/global-internet-will-likely-blackout-for-months-after-a-bad-solar-storm?amp_js_v=a6&amp_gsa=1&amp=1&usqp=mq331AQIKAGwASCAAgM%3D#aoh=16310477506837&csi=0&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fin.mashable.com%2Fscience%2F24574%2Fglobal-internet-will-likely-blackout-for-months-after-a-bad-solar-storm) I found in reddit that a solar storm could potentially hit Earth and knock out our internet and fry our sensitive electronics for months. If it did happen, how significant would the effects be, especially in our economy, today?

Comment: Can't watch TikTok videos for a while - the world is ending!

Comment: I wrote an answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/258093/59023 that is very much related to this question.  A slightly less related answer can be found at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/233126/59023

Comment: Oh okay then, thanks @honeste_vivere! Also @Jon Custer, I don't have Tiktok and I don't really watch them lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a Coronal Mass Ejection (CME) cause a blackout on Earth and why?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146779/can-a-coronal-mass-ejection-cme-cause-a-blackout-on-earth-and-why)